# Xcode UI Test Unable to Find the passwordTextField

Tags: ios, xcode

I am writing a simple UI Test in Xcode and running into issues. I have usernameTextField and passwordTextField. I am not able to refer to the passwordTextField. Here is my test along with the error.

```
func test_should_create_an_account_and_take_them_to_confirmation_screen() {

        let usernameTextField = self.app.textFields["usernameTextField"]
        usernameTextField.tap()
        usernameTextField.typeText("johndoe")

        let passwordTextField = self.app.textFields["passwordTextField"]
        passwordTextField.tap()
        passwordTextField.typeText("password123")

        self.app.buttons["registerButton"].tap()

        XCTAssertEqual(self.app.navigationBars.element.identifier, "BankAccount.LoginViewController")

    }
```

[image]

Comment: It automatically runs on simulator. It does fill out the usernameTextField successfully but on passwordTextField it fails.

Comment: I unselected it and now it works. Why does it even type in username correctly and fails on password. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks! If you can post that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the error it is able to find the text field just fine, it just can't activate the keyboard.

In Simulator, Hardware > Keyboard > Connect Hardware Keyboard, make sure it is not selected.

Probably you have the username field set to become first responder in `viewDidLoad` or something like that so that's why it works for one but not the other.

(I haven't seen a reliable solution for turning off the hardware keyboard programmatically when running tests, but if anyone knows one I would love to know. Unfortunately I think this setting resets when the Simulator is quit.)

Another solution would be to toggle the software keyboard, but with the hardware keyboard disconnected that should be more reliable.